# Problemas de conexión con la base de datos en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mariadb

Tengo instalado un sitio wordpress sin problema, quise hacer otro más en la misma PC, pero con diferente BD claro.
Creo la DB en MariaDB, descompacto el wordpress en la carpeta www/html/ y me crea la carpeta wordpress.

Voy a Mariadb con el siguiente comando
mariadb -u root -p

Ya dentro de Mariadb creo la base de datos

CREATE DATABASE wordpress;

Con SHOW DATABASES:
Verifico que la bd está creada

Entonces voy al navegador y tecleo localhost/worpress

Doy el nombre de usuario y contraseña de Mariadb.

Y wordpress me muestra el siguiente  mensaje.

Hemos podido conectar con el servidor de la base de datos (lo que significa que tu nombre de usuario y contraseña son correctos), pero no ha sido posible seleccionar la base de datos

He repetido con distintas bases de datos, nombre de sitio, con el usuario root y nada.

Lo más curioso que el otro sitio está trabajando bien.

Espero por su ayuda.

Gracias

Lino H.

Comment: Verificá que el archivo `wp-config.php` tenga los datos correctos para `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_HOST`. Ambos sitios deben estar, además, en carpetas distintas o distintos vhosts.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Pero realmente el problema era que Mariadb exige desde hace algún tiempo que se le otorguen los permisos de acceso a la base de datos al usuario con que se quiera acceder.